# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. while running project

Tags: android, android-manifest

My project was lost due to hard disc crash.But I had apk file. I decompiled it and used the manifist file from decompiled project in my last backup project. Now it's throwing error. I follow the suggestion given in error log but in vain.I'm putting here my error log and manifist file. Please help me for doing this job.here is my manifest file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.junaidsaif.dishdo">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".General.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="5d2875712018223074fecf326eb18d66b1d7b271" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SignIn"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="redirect"
                    android:scheme="sociallogin" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SignUp"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SignUpTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="redirect"
                    android:scheme="sociallogin" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Home"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.MyRecipe"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.SearchRecipe"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.TopRatedRecipe"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Setting"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.Cousine"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.AddRecipe"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.TabActivities.AddRecipeTabs.Image"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.TabActivities.AddRecipeTabs.Ingredients"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.TabActivities.AddRecipeTabs.Method"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.TabActivities.AddRecipeTabs.TimeServes"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity

            android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.ShareEmailActivity"
            tools:replace="android:configChanges"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/tw__transparent"
            android:label="@string/kit_name" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.Edit_Profile"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my error log. please help me.

```html
E:\2B VISION\DishDo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:122:13-48 Error:
 Attribute activity#com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity@configChanges value=(orientation) from AndroidManifest.xml:122:13-48
 is also present at [com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.3] AndroidManifest.xml:30:13-59 value=(orientation|screenSize).
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity@configChanges value=(orientation) from AndroidManifest.xml:122:13-48
 is also present at [com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.6.3] AndroidManifest.xml:30:13-59 value=(orientation|screenSize).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:configChanges"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:120:9-124:40 to override.
See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:configChanges"' to <activity> element at AndroidManifest.xml:120:9-124:40 to override.
:app:processDebugManifest FAILED
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 55.803 secs
Information:1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to replace

```
<activity
    android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:exported="false" />
```

with:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    tools:replace="android:configChanges"
    android:exported="false" />
```